# using javascript find div tag display property is none or block or undefined

Tags: javascript, html

using that code i am able to find tag display propery
but i want to get all the tag which have their display property none.Give me the result using javascript or jquery

document.getElementById('MSO_ContentTable').style.display

**MSO_ContentTable** is an id of div tag

Comment: You want to find all hidden tags? What are you trying to achieve, what's the end goal?

Comment: i am calculating total word in html page . i want to remove all the tag from calculation which have their display property none

Comment: Gave you an answer. With that selector you will find all the hidden elements of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none'; //or whatever you want to filter.
})
```

See it in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/WkxKc/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':hidden')
```

That should do just fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can try the below code to find all the elements which are hidden on the page

```
$("*").is(":hidden").not("input:hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

If a jquery solution is okay you could do:

```
     $('*:not(:visible)')
```

this returns a collection of all non visible objects in the dom.

These are elements that:

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page

You could filter out only those with "display:none" by iterating on them

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :
    $("#MSO_ContentTable").css("display","none");
Using Jquery ,
All document by id "MSO_ContentTable" is Gone ....